# What does ^ mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

This method returns the hash value of an object.
The instance variables are `item_name` and `qty`, which are both 
`attr_reader` variables.

What does `^` do?

```
def hash
  self.item_name.hash ^ self.qty.hash
end
```

Comment: I think I found the answer, in Ruby the ^ operator is for XOR.

Comment: http://symbolhound.com is useful when searching for syntax.